# What did I do wrong in the expansion or consideration of proof

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex numbers and satisfy the condition $|z_1+z_2|=|z_1-z_2|$, then show arguments of $z_1$ and $z_2$ are $\frac{\pi}{2}$ apart

I consider $z_1=r_1\cos(\theta_1)+r_1\sin(\theta)i$ and $z_2=r_2\cos(\theta_2)+r_2\sin(\theta_2)i$ but after expansion and cancel of the term, I get the equation $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)=-\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$?

$\theta_1-\theta_2=-(\theta_1-\theta_2)$

Comment: so $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)=0$

Comment: What you state is false. If two complex numbers have the same argument then they lie on a line through the origin and so their sum and difference have different lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the claim the text "apart." is missing.

The equation $|z_1+z_2|=|z_1-z_2|$ is equivalent with $|z_1+z_2|^2=|z_1-z_2|^2$, and this is equivalent with $z_1\bar z_2+\bar z_1 z_2=0$, or ${\rm Re}(z_1\bar z_2)=0$. Writing $z_k=x_k+i y_k$ $(k=1, \>2)$ the last says that
$$x_1x_2+y_1y_2=0\ .$$
This means that the ${\mathbb R}^2$-vectors ${\bf z}_k:=(x_k,y_k)$ are orthogonal, so that $\arg(z_1)$ and $\arg(z_2)$ are ${\pi\over2}$ apart.

Comment: Hi thanks, indeed i missed out the word "apart."